# How to keep border fixed on body while scrolling along with CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, layout, border

I am using css grid display for elements which are in the center and applying colored border on left and right side of the page to fill the white space using body element.

The problem is border does not fit the screen vertically. It only covers the grid-container. So if I use `height: 100vh;`on body, it works but when more elements are added to the grid-container and we scroll down, it stops at one point.

There is also a background image on body but it stays fixed because of `background-attachment: fixed;`.

Is there anything similar I can do for borders?

[JSFiddle showing similar issue](https://jsfiddle.net/97tnfakw/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't style to `<body>` , make a new container and give container a border

```css
      body{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .container {
            text-align: center;

              border-left:15em solid red ;
            border-right:15em solid red ;
            
        }

        .grid-element {
            width: 70%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: justify;
            background: #fff;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="grid-element">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis vero maxime, dolores, mollitia ducimus quo
                asperiores ea dolore deleniti saepe, voluptate ullam. Numquam nihil vel ea similique eius nobis
                possimus?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis vero maxime, dolores, mollitia ducimus quo
                asperiores
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis vero maxime, dolores, mollitia ducimus
                    quo asperiores ea dolore deleniti saepe, voluptate ullam. Numquam nihil vel ea
                    similique eius nobis possimus?</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis vero maxime, dolores, mollitia ducimus
                    quo asperiores ea dolore deleniti saepe, voluptate ullam. Numquam nihil vel ea
                    similique eius nobis possimus?</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis vero maxime, dolores, mollitia ducimus
                    quo asperiores ea dolore deleniti saepe, voluptate ullam. Numquam nihil vel ea
                    similique eius nobis possimus?</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis vero maxime, dolores, mollitia ducimus
                    quo asperiores ea dolore deleniti saepe, voluptate ullam. Numquam nihil vel ea
                    similique eius nobis possimus?</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis vero maxime, dolores, mollitia ducimus
                    quo asperiores ea dolore deleniti saepe, voluptate ullam. Numquam nihil vel ea
                    similique eius nobis possimus?</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis vero maxime, dolores, mollitia ducimus
                    quo asperiores ea dolore deleniti saepe, voluptate ullam. Numquam nihil vel ea
                    similique eius nobis possimus?</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis vero maxime, dolores, mollitia ducimus
                    quo asperiores ea dolore deleniti saepe, voluptate ullam. Numquam nihil vel ea
                    similique eius nobis possimus?</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis vero maxime, dolores, mollitia ducimus
                    quo asperiores ea dolore deleniti saepe, voluptate ullam. Numquam nihil vel ea
                    similique eius nobis possimus?</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis vero maxime, dolores, mollitia ducimus
                    quo asperiores ea dolore deleniti saepe, voluptate ullam. Numquam nihil vel ea
                    similique eius nobis possimus?</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis vero maxime, dolores, mollitia ducimus
                    quo asperiores ea dolore deleniti saepe, voluptate ullam. Numquam nihil vel ea
                    similique eius nobis possimus?</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis vero maxime, dolores, mollitia ducimus
                    quo asperiores ea dolore deleniti saepe, voluptate ullam. Numquam nihil vel ea
                    similique eius nobis possimus?</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis vero maxime, dolores, mollitia ducimus
                    quo asperiores ea dolore deleniti saepe, voluptate ullam. Numquam nihil vel ea
                    similique eius nobis possimus?</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis vero maxime, dolores, mollitia ducimus
                    quo asperiores ea dolore deleniti saepe, voluptate ullam. Numquam nihil vel ea
                    similique eius nobis possimus?</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis vero maxime, dolores, mollitia ducimus
                    quo asperiores ea dolore deleniti saepe, voluptate ullam. Numquam nihil vel ea
                    similique eius nobis possimus?</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis vero maxime, dolores, mollitia ducimus
                    quo asperiores ea dolore deleniti saepe, voluptate ullam. Numquam nihil vel ea
                    similique eius nobis possimus?</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis vero maxime, dolores, mollitia ducimus
                    quo asperiores ea dolore deleniti saepe, voluptate ullam. Numquam nihil vel ea
                    similique eius nobis possimus?</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis vero maxime, dolores, mollitia ducimus
                    quo asperiores ea dolore deleniti saepe, voluptate ullam. Numquam nihil vel ea
                    similique eius nobis possimus?</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis vero maxime, dolores, mollitia ducimus
                    quo asperiores ea dolore deleniti saepe, voluptate ullam. Numquam nihil vel ea
                    similique eius nobis possimus?</p>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```